# Designing scripting in a game without too much coupling

Tags: c++, scripting, v8, decoupling, coupling

I am making a 3D game in C++ using OGRE, and I'd like to implement scripting. So I have a subproject engine which directly "talk" with OGRE, and an another subproject v8-scripting which provides a V8Interface class which has a function init for the moment. my main.cpp is the butter between both and call Interface's init and run the engine. So the Interface init contained a simple hello world, and now I'd like to implement scriopting. Here is an example of what I'd like to obtain in js:

```
 Engine.on("update", function(event) {
         // called on every ogre frameQueued
  });
 var ent = Engine.getEntityById("0x2A");
 ent.setPosition(20, 20, 20);
```

**I'm not asking how to write such interface using v8, I'd like to know how to make the c++ implementations of exposed functions communicate with the engine** I'd like the engine not to care about the v8-scripting (because I might also provide lua and mono), the V8Interface might use directly the engine but it would be best if the main.cpp bind everything.

I know I can pass functions to functions but since there might be a lot of these, it would get messy.

Comment: Look into [lua](http://lua.org/) or [guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch you misunderstood me. I'm not asking tools (anyway it's off-topic), I have V8, I want to know how to make my subprojects communicate without coupling

Comment: So you want something like [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) working for V8?

Comment: No more ^^ I'm not asking a tool or a lib which is here off topic but a **design pattern**